# How do I allow users to add members to a specific database role?

Tags: sql-server-2012, role, permissions

I want to GRANT permissions to a new database role so that defined users can add and remove members from that role WITHOUT granting ALTER ANY ROLE permissions.

Here's how my query runs/dies:

```
CREATE ROLE [NewDBRole]
GO
```

The command(s) completed successfully.

```
GRANT ALTER ON [NewDBRole] TO [domain\username] WITH GRANT OPTION AS DBO
GO
```

This statement returns this error:

> Server: Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find the object 'NewDBRole', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

But clearly the Role exists and I do have permissions, because I am able to DROP it:

```
DROP ROLE [NewDBRole]
GO
```

This statement works fine and returns:

> The command(s) completed successfully.

Is there special syntax needed for this GRANT, and if so, what syntax will be required to REVOKE it in the future?

Comment: It appears the CASCADE option will be required for the REVOKE to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the syntax diagram](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173848.aspx) a little more carefully. Typically, above object level, you must specify the type you are applying permissions to with `<entity_type>::<entity_name>`.

```
GRANT ALTER ON ROLE::[NewDBRole] TO [domain\username] WITH GRANT OPTION AS dbo;
```